# How do you unpin member in visual studio when it errors

Tags: visual-studio

I created a pin for debugging (pin member as favorite) but I cannot unpin it, because the pin causes errors and I don't have access to view where unpinning was possible.
I have already tried resetting visual studio settings but the pin still exists

[error in locals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAPFS.png)